# How to check if publishing is on using CSOM?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing, client-object-model

How to check using CSOM if a web has publishing infrastructure and publishing features enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Server Object Model the method [PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.ispublishingweb%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is used to verify whether the [SPWeb](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms473942) object is a [PublishingWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object:

```
if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web))
{
    //
}
```

---

Regarding Client Object Model (CSOM), it actually depends on what version of SharePoint is used.

### SharePoint 2013

In SharePoint 2013 support for Publishing API was introduced.

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164782.aspx):

> Provides a large set of classes for developing custom plugins and apps
>   for interacting publishing pages in SharePoint Server 2013

To determine whether [Web](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee537040) is a [PublishingWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.publishingweb.aspx) the [PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.publishingweb.getpublishingweb.aspx) method could be used:

```
public static PublishingWeb GetPublishingWeb(
    ClientRuntimeContext context,
    Web web
)
```

Example:

```
var pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(context, context.Web);
context.Load(pWeb);
if (pWeb != null)
{
   //..
}
```

### SharePoint 2010

Publishing API is **not** supported via CSOM in SharePoint 2010

To determine whether Web is a Publishing Web the following code could be used:

```
    //Publishing Web Client Object for  SharePoint 2010 (CSOM)
    public class PublishingWeb
    {

        public PublishingWeb(Web web)
        {
            this._web = web;
        }


        public static bool ReturnIsPublishingWebProperty(Web web)
        {
            EnsureWeb(web);
            return GetProperty(web, "__PublishingFeatureActivated", false);
        }     

        private static void EnsureWeb(Web web)
        {
            var ctx = web.Context;
            if(web.AllProperties.FieldValues.Count == 0)
            {
                ctx.Load(web, w => w.AllProperties);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }


        private static T GetProperty<T>(Web web,string propName, T defaultPropValue)
        {
            if (!web.AllProperties.FieldValues.ContainsKey(propName))
                return defaultPropValue;
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(web.AllProperties[propName], typeof(T));
        }

        private static void SetProperty<T>(Web web,string propName, T propValue)
        {
            web.AllProperties[propName] = propValue;
        }


        private Web _web;


    }
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7926168)

Example:

```
if (PublishingWeb.ReturnIsPublishingWebProperty(context.Web))
{
   //...
}
```